# Can I get the JBoss CLI tool to report the exception that caused my deployment to fail?

Tags: deployment, jboss, jboss7.x, error-reporting, command-line-interface

I’m using JBoss 7.1.3.Final.  When deploying using the CLI tool, is it possible to also output the exception that occurred in the logs that caused a deployment to fail?  We run an automated nightly deployment, and I’d like to be able to report the exception in an email rather than force people to log into the machine and go through the server logs.  Here’s what I’m doing so far …

```
$ $JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=/tmp/my.cli
```

in which the contents of “my.cli” are

```
connect
deploy --force /tmp/my.war
```

However, what is reported right now on the commond line is

```
{"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./my" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./my: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"},"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"my.war\".jboss.security.jacc Missing[JBAS014861: <one or more transitive dependencies>]"]}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use mailing service with Jboss([here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Mail+Subsystem?_sscc=t) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240779/configure-gmail-in-jboss-7-1-1)), but I don't know how you the can be incorporated from `jboss-cli`. So my preference will be send the mail with taking responsibility on your hand!

I am assuming your `jboss` is running at `linux` server:

When you run the deployment command, take the output into a shell variable(if it returns any). For example:

```
deploy_response = $( $JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=/tmp/my.cli )
```

Or, if the log is written into a log-file, then read the last few lines(you know how many lines usually is written when an error occurs) into a variable.

```
## readling last 3 lines and joining them into one line
deploy_response = $( tail -n3 /your/log/file.log | tr "\\n" " ")
```

Now, you have the deployment response in your hand. Check for the error msg over there. Usually the Jboss errors are use to be in this format `JBASxxxxxx`. So this will be useful to detect the jboss error.

```
## if [[ $deploy_response == *Composite operation failed* ]]
if [[ $deploy_response =~ JBAS\d\d\d\d\d\d ]]
then
   ## assuming you have send mail is configured.
   echo $deploy_response | mail -s "jboss deployment error" admins@localdomain.com
fi
```

Comment: Regarding getting the lines from the log file, getting the last 3 lines won't do it.  Sometimes the error that cuases the deployment to fail spans more than just the last 3 lines.

Comment: Got your point. That case you can rotate the log file. I mean when you run the deployment, then move old log to archive and create new log file every time. Then read the whole file for the error msg(`cat file.log`).

Comment: Because I'm trying to automate this whole thing, reading a potentially multi-giga byte file for the error is not an option.  I'm curious as to whether I can get the error message that caused the failure from the CLI tool, and if not, if there's some other automated way of figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Maven Wildfly Deployment](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/index.html) it will output the error to the log. Then you can simply have your CI tool email the failure log.